# What should I do with my answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

This [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/23531/7476) of mine has collected a fair amount of comments concerning the correctness (or lack thereof) of the first image that I posted, a screenshot of a fraction of Google Maps with 2 circles on it.

Circles that have been added after some comments asked for them, as otherwise it was not easy to follow what I was saying in the answer itself.

Now someone is asking for the removal of said image because, [according to them](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/what-is-doklams-strategic-importance-for-india-and-china/23531?noredirect=1#comment82964_23531)

> The first map at the top of your post is wrong [...] The Diplomat and Vatsrohit are correct.

Now this quote condenses my problem: "Vatsrohit" (one of the links given in the comment and that I then included in the answer) explicitly says that the area that I have circled in black is "agreed as disputed by Bhutan and China" and is called "Doklam plateau as per Google Maps", something that I point out in my answer.

Nevertheless [I am told](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/what-is-doklams-strategic-importance-for-india-and-china/23531?noredirect=1#comment83072_23531)

> the black circled area and your first bullet point are wrong. Trust me. I was bothered by the lack of clarity and went through all the Bhutan National Assembly archives. Nowhere is there any mention of a so-called "Doklam plateau" in that area. The only Doklam plateau is in the trijunction area.

I sincerely do not understand how this conflicts with my answer:

- I acknowledge that generally that area is know as the plateau (as said by the "correct" source)
- I point out that the question is referring to another area

Should I consider my answer "wrong"?
Should I edit it somehow? (please suggest what I should edit, then)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in this specific subject area, so I can't comment on the correctness of your image, so this answer will focus more on tactics for handling content disputes.

- You should try to verify for yourself what the correct answer is.  Unless you have a specific reason to believe that the commenter really does know better than you do, you need not take his word for it.
- It might be worth while to reconcile your understanding of the facts with the commenter's and try to understand **why** he believes the way he does.  Doing so can help you more fully refine your answer. However, if you can't reconcile with him, then you're under not obligation to accept his analysis.